# Can a raspberry pi 3 which has a hostpot get internet access via my phone mobile data?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, hotspot

If i created a hot-spot with a raspberry pi 3 that isn't connect to the Internet, then connected my phone to that hot-spot,then turned on my mobile data on my phone, can the raspberry pi get Internet access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If i created a hot-spot with a raspberry pi 3 that isn't connect to the Internet, then connected my phone to that hot-spot,then turned on my mobile data on my phone, can the raspberry pi get Internet access?

No. This would require the Pi to connect to the phone's hotspot instead.  The issue is that this is the only way the phone will route for the Pi.

Comment: Okay, so there is no workaround. How about setting a default wire less ssid and password for the pi to connect to whenever its available? In that case whenever any mobile device creates a hotspot with a particular hotspot with ssid: freewifi and password:password, then the pi connects to that. Would that pi connect to that wifi if any device creates such a wireless network?

Comment: You can't be running a hotspot on the pi and scan for other networks at the same time, unless you have two wifi interfaces.  If you aren't running a hotspot on the pi then you could set something like that up.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it works like that, but a good idea could be to get internet access to your Raspberry Pi 3 somehow (probably by buying a Wifi Adapter), then you can use your cell phone's hotspot to give the Pi internet. If tried connecting via the Pi's hotspot, it could only connect to the ethernet network it was connected to and not the connected phone's data. Another issue with that is that the phone would connect to the hotspot and only the hotspot instead of using the mobile data, since it would believe it is connected to WiFi. Hope this helped.

Comment: The Raspberry Pi 3 has a built-in wifi adapter.   There is no such thing as an ethernet "hotspot".

Comment: @goldilocks I didn't know that it had a built-in wifi adapter. I mostly deal with a Pi 2 Model B which has ethernet, which I thought they were talking about something to broadcast that ethernet signal. Sorry for the confusion.